# Python concept. Else statement printing when it shouldn't

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

This is really a concept question from a beginning programmer. I am still  working on this program. When I type in a menu option not only does the corresponding if statement print but, the else statement does at well. With this python knowledge I have I do not understand why. I would like to know what is triggering my else statement.

```
    FIND_LOWEST_NUMBER_CHOICE = 1
    FIND_HIGHEST_NUMBER_CHOICE = 2
    FIND_TOTAL_CHOICE = 3
    FIND_AVERAGE_CHOICE = 4
    QUIT_CHOICE = 5

    def main():
        numbers = get_values()
        get_analysis(numbers)
    def get_values():
        print('Please enter 20 numbers')
        values =[]    
        for i in range(20):
            value =(int(input("Enter A Random Number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")))
            values.append(value)
        return values
    def get_analysis (numbers):
        choice = 0
        while choice != QUIT_CHOICE:
            display_menu()
            choice = int(input('Enter your choice:'))
            if choice == FIND_LOWEST_NUMBER_CHOICE:
                print("The Lowest Number Is:",  min(numbers))
            if choice == FIND_HIGHEST_NUMBER_CHOICE:
                print("The Highest Number Is:", max(numbers))
            if choice == FIND_TOTAL_CHOICE:
                print("The Sum The Numbers Is:", sum(numbers))
            if choice == FIND_AVERAGE_CHOICE:
                print("The Average The Numbers Is:", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
            if choice == QUIT_CHOICE:
                print("Exiting program....")
            else:
                print('Error')

    def display_menu():
        print(' Menu')
        print('1. Show lowest number')
        print('2. Show highest number')
        print('3. Show total of numbers')
        print('4. Show average of numbers')
        print('5. Quit')

    main()
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Use `elif` if you want to match the same variable against multiple values

Comment: Thank you. I think I have been staring out it too long I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use elif, because, in your code, the else just match the last if.

For example:

```
if choice == FIND_LOWEST_NUMBER_CHOICE:
    print("The Lowest Number Is:",  min(numbers))
elif choice == FIND_HIGHEST_NUMBER_CHOICE:
    print("The Highest Number Is:", max(numbers))
elif choice == FIND_TOTAL_CHOICE:
    print("The Sum The Numbers Is:", sum(numbers))
elif choice == FIND_AVERAGE_CHOICE:
    print("The Average The Numbers Is:", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
elif choice == QUIT_CHOICE:
    print("Exiting program....")
else:
    print('Error')
```